# onFocus stops firing after modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have where I use an onfocus event handler to do several things. It works great after initial page load. However, after I click on a link that opens a modal popup the onfocus event stops working. Focus still works fine... but the onfocus event is never fired again until the page is reloaded. How can focus happen without the onfocus event firing?

```
jQuery(":input").on("focus", function(e)
{
    console.log("Debug 1");
});
```

Before the modal popup this call fires the event handler above...

```
pTR.find("td:eq(13)").children(":first").focus();
```

After closing the popup that same call does give that element focus, but the event handler isnt fired.

How is this possible?

Comment: Does the modal manipulate the input, or is the input inside the modal?

Comment: The modal does change the value of one of the inputs. There are multiple inputs on the page and all of them have the same issue after using the popup... not just the one being manipulated.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand very well the question, but I think putting

```
e.preventDefault();
```

or

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

at the beginning of your onfocus event might help...

Try both depending of your situation.